# Trouble opening Android Bluetooth socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to connect my Android device to Pulse Sensor device that communicates over Bluetooth connection.

I followed the Android [Bluetooth Chat example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat), and here there is the core of my code:

```
BluetoothDevice mDevice = mBlueToothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC_DEVICE);

ParcelUuid[] uuids = mDevice.getUuids();
```

uuid contains just one entry with this value:

```
00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

After that I have this code:

```
BluetoothSocket mmSocket = device.
                      createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
```

here I can see that the state of the *mmSocket* is **INIT**.

Then I call:

```
mmSocket.connect();
```

that works just sometimes. Most of the time this call generates the following IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

If, from debugging, I check the status of the socket I can see that it is not closed, but it is yet in INIT state.

I have also tryed using the `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` method for creating the socket. And also I tried with the basic UUID:

```
00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

But with the same result.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which device you're working on??

Comment: My smartphone is a Samsung S4 Active (but I also tried with OnePlus One) while the bluetooth device that I want connect to, is a Pulse (also known as Body Gateway, created by STMicroelectronics)

Comment: I recently worked on this Bluetppth Chat demo. I faced the same kind of issue. and i got solution. I got 10 UUID generated from my Samsung S3. Now when i try one by one UUID some of working and some not. I just suggest you try one by one UUID. May be one of works..

Comment: I think I should use a UUID that the divice acting as server is configured to work on, depending on the service it provides. Since the device (Body Gateway) provides a SPP service I used the `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb UUID`, as said [here](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/service-discovery). However, which UUIDs you suggest to try?